# Why firefox showing some strings instead of Facebook in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, firefox, browser, facebook

I am using Mozilla Firefox 46.0.1 in windows 8 64 bit machine. I was browsing Facebook well,but suddenly when i was trying to browse Facebook from Firefox, instead of Facebook window some strings are showing in Firefox window. I have installed Kasparesky Antivirus. But in Google Choromo browser this problem is not happening. In the Same Firefox, other websites are working properly, they are being displayed properly.

Snapshot of the window has given below.

[image]

The page source snapshot has given below:

[image]

The Encoding Scheme of the original page and the source page is same:

[image]

I have tried other encoding scheme but the result is same.

Here is the page info:

[image]

I have cleared cache and restarted the browser,but no change.
I have also off the private browsing of Kaspersky Antivirus.

Comment: My guess is that Firefox chose the wrong encoding for the web page's text/HTML.

Comment: @BenN, it may be, but other websites are working properly...

Comment: 1. Other urls are OK, right? 2. Does Page Source (Ctrl+U) display normal html? 3. What is the selected text encoding (alt - view - text encoding)?

Comment: @user3169 please check the edits...

Comment: And with this tab displayed, if you open a new tab and go to some other website, it displays OK?

Comment: BTW, I was looking for encoding scheme of the original page, not the source.

Comment: @user3169, it is same

Comment: @user3169, yes it is displaying other websites ,as i am using superuser.com....

Comment: How about trying it in Firefox Private Browsing or safe mode (addons disabled)?

Comment: @user3169, in private mode  it is same

Comment: Can you confirm other https:// sites display OK? I wonder if KAV is involved somehow.

Comment: @user3169, yes  other https:// sites are displayed..

Comment: Have you tried setting another encoding? Cleared your cache? Restarted? Is it possible to disable KAV temporarily? And probably a stupid question, but does View Page Info show oddities (different "Type" or anything)?

Comment: @Mr Lister , please check edits..

Comment: Could you confirm: 1. You are using Kaspersky Anti-Virus or Internet Security? Anti-Virus does not have the Private Browsing setting. 2. Did you try starting Firefox with add-ons disabled (alt - Help - Restart with Add-ons Disabled)?

Comment: @user3169, yes Kaspersky Anti-Virus or Internet Security and the problem solved after disabling the adds on and making off the private browsing. But it has solved without knowing proper reason...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with Kaspersky Private Browsing.

Open up KS and turn it off in the settings. If you just turn it off in the web browser it will keep having issues.

This just started happening today for me, so looks like Kaspersky stuffed up something.

[image]

Here is screen shot where to turn it off in Kaspersky
Make sure to restart FF after turning it off.

Comment: please edit this answer with ur previous answer..cas one answer can be chosen...and it will be helpful for other