# Weird login page on Facebook

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox

When I try to access Facebook I receive this login page:

[image: Facebook problem]

This happens only in Firefox and Chrome.

Things I have done:

1. Disabled my firewall.
2. Cleared my cookies and temp files.
3. Run a virus scan.
4. Reinstalled Chrome and Firefox.
5. Changed Encoding

Comment: Is it only Facebook this happens with? Or are there others sites that this happens? Disable any add-ins?

Comment: Did you try with IE?

Comment: If you click the green lock symbol what trust information do you see? (Ruling out some strange mitm attack)

Comment: @CharlieRB  Only in Facebook;  Dave In IE works fine. RJFalconer "HTTPS is secure, Valid Certificate"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why firefox showing some strings instead of Facebook in windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/1075427/why-firefox-showing-some-strings-instead-of-facebook-in-windows-8)

Comment: @user3169 Thank you. Your link help -me to solve the problem. I don't use Kaspersky but I added a exception rule to facebook.com on Avast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The was Avast.

In Avast configuration go to "Active Protection" >> Web Shield >> "Customize"

So I added facebook.com to exclusion list.

[image: Avast Exclusion list]